# Firebase phone auth error "APP_NOT_VERIFIED"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

There is a problem with firebase phone auth, for some devices there appearing error: `APP_NOT_VERIFIED`. Did not find the cause of this error, only mentioning in the list of all errors in the firebase documentation.

Comment: I have the same issue! Did you find out the cause?

Comment: @mesqueeb, still didn't  find

Comment: We get this for UK phone numbers... of the format `+44 07 111 1111`

Answer (score 0):

We were getting this issue for UK phone numbers... of the format `+44 07 111 1111`

I can confirm Google fixed this in the latest firebase SDK, update your .xcframeworks and this error will go away and logins work again for those users.

What a mess!

Comment: the problem sometimes occurs for KY phone numbers of the format +996 XXX XXX XXX

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing same issue
maybe your Firebase/Auth version is lower than 8.8.0; so try updating it if necessary to see if it will resolve the issue